# Set OnTouchListeners for dynamically generated ImageViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view

I am setting an `OnTouchListener` to a `ImageView` and then duplicating the same `ImageView` on  `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` as follows

```
if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        i++;
            image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setImageBitmap(btn.getDrawingCache());
            image.setId(i);
            //image.setOnTouchListener(dragit);
            layout.addView(image, i, params);
}
```

the same follows for ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP.

Now after the new View is generated I try to set an OnTouchListener for that as   `image.setOnTouchListener(dragit);`

But the problem is I can create 1000 such `ImageViews`, how do I end up recognizing them uniquely? I had set an id for each imageview but how do I reference it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add imageViews into an array or list and then in onTouch event compare the view with the views from your list

Answer (score 1):

layout.getChildAt(y++).getId()

Answer (score 1):

In **your onClickListener** you must be getting **View v as parameter** using that you can get to know which view it is,like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId(); // id that you have set 
}
```